# iOS UIToolBar gets hidden on Keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield, uitextview, uitoolbar

In my ViewController on bottom I have a UIToolBar (myToolbar), in that I have a UITextField (messageTxt) and a button. When I try to write anything on messageTxt, the keyboard comes up but it hides the toolbar. Due to this, until I don't close the keyboard I can't know what I have typed. 
I am looking for, when I start typing I should be able to see what I am typing. For that, maybe maybe make the view smaller & add keyboard below or how can this be implemented.

For other sites, I implemented the following but yet can't see what I am typing. I can see the suggestions while typing, but not what I am typing. Can you help me know where am I going wrong. My code is :-

In my viewDidLoad method, have added these 2 notifications for keyboard.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

[super viewDidLoad];
```

Implementation of the notification methods .

```
-(void) keyboardWillShow: (NSNotification *) notification {
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve = [[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    CGRect keyboardBounds = [(NSValue *) [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    [self.myToolBar setFrame:CGRectMake(30.0f, self.view.frame.size.height - keyboardBounds.size.height - self.myToolBar.frame.size.height,    self.myToolBar.frame.size.width, self.myToolBar.frame.size.height)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

-(void) keyboardWillHide: (NSNotification *) notification {
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve = [[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    CGRect keyboardBounds = [(NSValue *) [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];

    [self.myToolBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, self.view.frame.size.height - 46.0f, self.myToolBar.frame.size.width, self.myToolBar.frame.size.height)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Added lastly this TextDelegate method, to know when it has focus.

```
-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

   //[self.messageTxt setInputAccessoryView:self.myToolBar];
}
```

Where am I going wrong or what is missing in my code ? 
One more point, I wish to implement TextView inlace of TextField - as I want multi-lines input. I believe that is possible and with the above implementation with TExtView won't be any issues too. Is adding TextView and Button in View instead of ToolBar better option for the same or it can be managed well with ToolBar ? What is better option ?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In view didload method put code:

```
txtfield.inputAccessoryView = (Instance of your UIToolbar)
```

Other code as written above are ok.  You should set AccessoryView before keyboard appear so This will show toolbar when keyboard will be open.

Comment: I added above line in my viewDidLoad method & I got constraints error :-  Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
 Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) ......   I am using AutoLayout. Above ToolBar is TableView & have constraints set with TableView & of ToolBar Horizontal space, vertical space, Leading, Trailing alignment. All of them are Equal to 0.

Comment: I have Vertical Space - View - Toolbar & Vertical Space - Bottom Layout Guide - Toolbar which I think might causing problem. Both's values are set 0. I added a NSLayoutConstraint kbHeight & set to View-Toolbar constraint. Tried making it <= 0, >= 0. Tried the dame making it 0 & setting kbHeight to Bottom Layout Guide-Toolbar constraint & making it <= 0 & >= 0. But all trying gave same results - same error and nothing is seen on the screen. In code, instead of setting myToolbar setHeight, altered the constraint value. If both constraint doesn't work,Which constraint do I have to set ???

Comment: Can you please guide.

Comment: I have added self.messageTxt.inputAccessoryView = self.myToolBar;  Am I doing any mistake here - messageTxt is in myToolBar only. Is this correct ???

Comment: On your textfields instance you need to set the toolbar.  e.g: UITextfield *tf;  you can set, tf.inputAccessoryView = self.myToolbar.